# is there a solution to this JoinForkTask problem?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, forkjoinpool

this code multiplies the elements of an array by a given number , if the array length > THRESHOLD the code breaks the array into 100 small arrays and does the process with a RecurciveAction  . But i don t know why it doesn't show any results .
PS. the code is working perfectly if the array length < THRESHOLD
here is the full code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ArrayTransform extends RecursiveAction {

    
    
    private int arr[];
    private final int THRESHOLD =100;

    

    private int multiplyBy;

    public ArrayTransform(int arr[], int multiplyBy) {
        this.multiplyBy = multiplyBy;
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    private List<ArrayTransform> tasks() {
        List<ArrayTransform> tasks = new ArrayList<>(arr.length / 100);
        // BREAKING the array into 100 arrays
        int breakpoint = 99;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length / 100; i++) {
            if (tasks.isEmpty() ) {
                tasks.add(i, new ArrayTransform(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, 99), multiplyBy));

            } else {

                tasks.add(i, new ArrayTransform(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, breakpoint+1 , breakpoint + 100), multiplyBy));
                breakpoint += 100;
            }
        }
        
        return tasks;
    }

    private void multiply(int arr[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            arr[i] = arr[i] * multiplyBy;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (arr.length < THRESHOLD) {
            multiply(arr);

        } else {

            ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(tasks());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int test[] = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10000).toArray();
        System.out.println("original array :"+Arrays.toString(test));
        ForkJoinPool common = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();

        common.invoke(new ArrayTransform(test, 2));
        System.out.println("after transformation :"+Arrays.toString(test));
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You generate an array in the `main` method, pass it to your class and inspect the original array.

Your method `tasks()` performs the split and copies the original array data into new arrays that are privately held by the new `ArrayTransform` objects.
The modified data is never transferred back into the original array.